# Add N empty rows between each value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which sums every 5 rows in 'Costs' and puts into 'Sum'. Now I would like to add 4 empty rows between each value in 'Sum' to have it at the start of each 5 rows.
What would be the most efficient and straight forward way to achieve this?

Input:

```
  Costs |  Sum  
 -------|------- 
   1000 | 10000 
   1500 | 22500 
   2000 | 35000 
   2500 |       
   3000 |       
   3500 |       
   4000 |       
   4500 |       
   5000 |       
   5500 |       
   6000 |       
   6500 |       
   7000 |       
   7500 |       
   8000 |
```

Output:

```
  Costs |  Sum  
 -------|------- 
   1000 | 10000 
   1500 |       
   2000 |       
   2500 |       
   3000 |       
   3500 | 22500 
   4000 |       
   4500 |       
   5000 |       
   5500 |       
   6000 | 35000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC ,you can repeat the Sum column and check for the first of the duplicated value , then assign:

```
n=5
u = df['Sum'].replace('',np.nan).dropna().repeat(n)
df['New_sum'] = np.where(~u.index.duplicated(),u,'')
```

---

```
print(df)

    Costs    Sum New_sum
0    1000  10000   10000
1    1500  22500        
2    2000  35000        
3    2500               
4    3000               
5    3500          22500
6    4000               
7    4500               
8    5000               
9    5500               
10   6000          35000
11   6500               
12   7000               
13   7500               
14   8000
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `groupby` + `transform` then `mask` the duplicated values:

```
g = df.index // 5
df['Sum'] = df['Costs'].groupby(g).transform('sum').mask(g.duplicated(), '')
```

Result:

```
    Costs    Sum
0    1000  10000
1    1500       
2    2000       
3    2500       
4    3000       
5    3500  22500
6    4000       
7    4500       
8    5000       
9    5500       
10   6000  35000
11   6500       
12   7000       
13   7500       
14   8000
```